# How to find the distinct error messages of model state validation failure in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, modelstate

I want to filter the **Error Messages** that gets populated as part of data annotation modelstate validation failure. As in if an array of objects comes as a part of class, and the validation fails for more than one object, I do not want the same message to be added again and again. Instead, I want to find the distinct error messages

```
  string ValidationFailure= string.Join(";", actionContext.ModelState.Values.Distinct().Select(x.ErrorMessage));
```

But not able to get the required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your attempt is close, but you’re using `Distinct` on something that’s already unique (`Values`). Instead, try the following variation:

```
string ValidationFailure = string.Join(";", actionContext.ModelState.Values.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).Distinct());
```

This ensures that you get a distinct list of `ErrorMessage`s.